# Why does any number divided by 0.7 look the same?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\frac{1}{0.7} = 1.42857142857...$

$\frac{0.8}{0.7} = 1.142857...$

$\frac{0.3}{0.7} = 0.42857142857...$

$\frac{0.33}{0.7} = 0.47142857...$

Why does any number divided by seven seem to follow this same pattern of $142857$?

Does this apply to every scenario $\frac{a}{b} $ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ or even $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Edit: Of course it doesn't apply to all numbers, for example, the obvious $\frac{0.7}{0.7}$ or $\frac{0.35}{0.7}$

So the question should be, which combinations of numbers does it apply to and why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/142,857

Comment: @ElliotG Awesome! I never would have thought looking up these digits would lead to an article on Wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same reason that any non-multiple of $3$ that is divided by $3$ will have a repeating decimal of $\space333\cdots.\space $ We have
$\quad\dfrac{1}{7}=
0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428\cdots
\space$ and any multiple will still have the trailing repeating decimal, at least as a factor,  unless the multiple has $7$ as a factor.